# Parse iOS - How to save an PFObject locally and manually upload to server later?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, save, local-datastore

I want to create a PFObject and have it saved locally so that if the user quits the app (or heaven forbid, it crashes) the object is still intact on the device BUT not uploaded to the server until the user is ready to submit it. Is this possible?

I know there is the 'saveEventually' method, but my understanding of that is it will at some point save itself to the server automatically, which is not what I want. I want to save locally only and only upload to the server when the user is completed finished.

Comment: Yes, you could save the various components of that PFObject locally then reassemble them into a PFObject once you're ready to save to Parse...

Comment: Yeah I was hoping Parse had a built in method to just save/cache a new object locally. Hoping to not have to save each property of the object as it can be quite large and contain many types of data.

Comment: Then you can use Parse's Local Datastore: http://blog.parse.com/2014/12/09/parse-local-datastore-for-ios/

Comment: I need this often, too.  The best thing for me so far has been to wrap my PFObjects in an NSObject that implements NSCoding and then archive them.  There's a resource or two (google 'PFObject NSCoding') out there that tries to do this without the NSObject wrapper, but all the stuff I found was hacky and temperamental.  I can post my simple-minded solution if you're interested.

Comment: @LyndseyScott - I don't think you fully understand. I know how to use the local data store, but that is only useful for saving existing items from the Parse server. I want to create a new object locally and have it persist sessions WITHOUT saving it to the Parse server until I want it to.

Comment: @danh - I was afraid this would be the case. I just wanted to avoid NSCoding approach if possible since you have to specify encoding/decoding of every property, and my object may change over time.

Comment: I went the NSCoding + Parse route before and one pitfall I wanted to warn you about was that files not specifically marked to avoid backup are backed up to iCloud but the Parse database isn't. This caused me some headaches in the past. Anyways pinObjectInBackground() is what I use for this now instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have enabled the local datastore, calling `pinObjectInBackground()` on an object should make the object persist between sessions. Every time you make changes to the object that you want to save, call `pinObjectInBackground()` again. The object will not be saved to the server until you call `saveEventually()` or some other save function. Any query using `fromLocalDatastore()` will be able to fetch your locally stored object as long as it is pinned.